# Changing PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS

Tags: php, apache-2.4, fastcgi, apache2, plesk

I cannot find the location of the conf file where I can change the value of `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS`. Info about the system: Debian, php7, FAST-CGI, Apache 2.4, Plesk Onyx 17.

There are similar questions on the web, but none of the answers helped me to solve the issue.

I set `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1500` so I need to change the value of `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS`, as well.

The output of `plesk bin php_handler --list`

```
                  id:        display name:  full version:  version:    type:                         cgi-bin:                    php-cli:                        php.ini:  custom:  status:
                  cgi  5.6.33 by OS vendor         5.6.33       5.6      cgi                /usr/bin/php5-cgi               /usr/bin/php5           /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini    false disabled
              fastcgi  5.6.33 by OS vendor         5.6.33       5.6  fastcgi                /usr/bin/php5-cgi               /usr/bin/php5           /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini    false  enabled
                  fpm  5.6.33 by OS vendor         5.6.33       5.6      fpm               /usr/sbin/php5-fpm               /usr/bin/php5           /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini    false  enabled
               module  5.6.33 by OS vendor         5.6.33       5.6   module                /usr/bin/php5-cgi               /usr/bin/php5       /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini    false disabled
      plesk-php56-cgi               5.6.34         5.6.34       5.6      cgi   /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php-cgi  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini     true disabled
  plesk-php56-fastcgi               5.6.34         5.6.34       5.6  fastcgi   /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php-cgi  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini     true  enabled
      plesk-php56-fpm               5.6.34         5.6.34       5.6      fpm  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/sbin/php-fpm  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php  /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini     true  enabled
      plesk-php71-cgi               7.1.15         7.1.15       7.1      cgi   /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php-cgi  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/etc/php.ini     true disabled
  plesk-php71-fastcgi               7.1.15         7.1.15       7.1  fastcgi   /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php-cgi  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/etc/php.ini     true  enabled
      plesk-php71-fpm               7.1.15         7.1.15       7.1      fpm  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/sbin/php-fpm  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php  /opt/plesk/php/7.1/etc/php.ini     true  enabled
```

Comment: do you have FastCgiExternalServer in your Apache config? How do you start the fastcgi server?

Comment: How to check if I have or not? I could not find FastCgiExternalServer inside apache.conf and 000-default.conf. I chose fastcgi in php settings in plesk panel.

Comment: I had missed the 'plesk' bit. Can you post the output of: plesk bin php_handler --list

Comment: I have updated the post as you asked.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem please accept it. If it didn't please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add:

> FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS   1500

before `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1500`.

That will set the environment variable PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS to 1500 before loading mod_fcgid.

More info at https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidinitialenv